# Magento2.3.4 Add green border when validation of input is succesfull on Checkout Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, checkout-page, success-message, input

When input is invalid we can see red border and error message below. Is it possible to add green border when input is valid ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick solution, it is working amazing

1. create you module or insert following code in theme requirejs-config.js
   Here the purpose of validation-mixin to extend original mage.validation.

> ```
> var config = {
>     config: {
>         mixins: {
>             'mage/validation': {
>                 'Expert_Checkout/js/mage/validation-mixin': true
>             }   
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

1. validation-mixin.js

> ```
> define([
>     'jquery' ], function ($) {
>     'use strict';
>     var widgetMixin = {
>         _create: function() {
>             $(this.element).find('input, textarea, select').on("change keyup", function(e){
>               $.validator.validateSingleElement(e.currentTarget)
>             });
>             return this._super();
>         }
>     };
>     return function (parentWidget) {
>         $.widget('mage.validation', parentWidget, widgetMixin);
>         return $.mage.validation;
>     }; })
> ```

Now it will work on all forms and validate field as user type and add class valid on success Or you can add custom class if you want

```
if($.validator.validateSingleElement(e.currentTarget))
$(e.currentTarget).addClass("no-error")
```

Thanks